# windows: how to stop irda dongle periodic auto detecting

Tags: c, windows, sockets, hardware, infrared

I'm writing some code in C for an IrDA project on one win7 32bit computer. I have another computer setup to display any data received via in infrared. This part works. However the as soon as I connect the IrDA dongle to the PC, it starts to send periodic data for searching other IrDA devices. I want to disable this behavior programmatically so I see only the data sends as a result of my code. Anyone know which command to use? Is it WSASetService? I didn't learn socket programming, not sure what "removes from the registry a service instance within one or more namespaces. " really means. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms742211%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Have you disabled the Infrared Monitor Service manually?

I experienced problems with this functionality in win7 when using Windows to communicating with an embedded micro-controller based device that worked well with windows XP.

I disabled the Infrared Monitor Service manually and found that windows was still polling the IrDA periodically!

I have not found any documentation available that describes it or how to disable it, I will continue searching...